# Suppress Excel compatibility check on macro

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, vba

I am trying to automate an Excel app. It has some macros which I have managed to trigger from code. The last macro generates a new Excel file which gives a compatibility check message box (97-2003). I tried suppressing it by below approach.

- By SendKeys("{ENTER}")
- Setting DisplayAlerts to false for Excel app
- Setting DefaultSaveFormat to xlExcel8
- Setting CheckCompatibility to false

I was able to handle other pop-ups by using SendKeys but this one seems different.

Thanks,
Souvik